# bs4: Differentiating between text and HTML-element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to seperate XSS-payloads to analyze their structure with different methods.
An example payload looks like this:

```
<picture><source srcset="x"><img onerror="***payload***"></picture>
```

Now I need to seperate the different parts to get the following output:

> picture source srcset x img onerror ***payload***

My problem is, that sometimes the payloads contain text content and sometimes another HTML-element, like in the example, as content. If I would simply append the content of the "upper" HTML-element, the output would be wrong, since I would iterate over that element a second time.

My code looks something like this:

```
for x in self.normalized_payloads:
tmp = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all()
for y in elements:
    tmp.append(y.name)
    for u in y.attrs.keys():    
        tmp.append(u)
        tmp.append(y.attrs[u])
seperated_payloads.append(tmp)
```

How can I differentiate between text and another HTML-element as content of an HTML-element? Do you have other ways of reaching this output, without iterating through every HTML-element of the payload?

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out I came up with a working solution:

```
if len(BeautifulSoup(y.decode_contents(formatter="html"),'html.parser').find_all()) == 0 and y.decode_contents(formatter="html") != "":
    tmp.append(y.decode_contents(formatter="html"))
```

This code checks, whether or not child elements are parseable HTML-elements or just text.